# How can I create a layout like this?

Tags: xetex, layout, page

[image]

I would like to have a larger left margin like in the picture above. I guess something like this would do it:

```
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.5in, right=1.5in]{geometry}
```

I think I should reduce the right one then.

However, I don't know how to add that gray bottom border for the first level headings and make the heading numbers go out of the left margin a little bit like in the picture above.

Can you give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Have you searched about that on this forum?

Comment: It should be easy to obtain with the optional argument of `\titleformat`  from `titlesec`.

Comment: You mean `titlespacing` and `titleformat`? I think `titlespacing` works to set a negative margin but how about that gray border?

Comment: @Black Mild I couldn't even find this layout template on the overleaf website so what makes you think that someone made something similar on this forum?

Comment: You may want to look at the `memoir` documentclass, for which various predefined  layout styles are already available as-is or for modification. The main manual (what you get from `texdoc memoir` is available from https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en. For samples, see also http://tug.ctan.org/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf and the images you get if you Google "latex memoir sample layout styles". Be aware, though, that designing and implementing a book layout is never a trivial matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using `titlesec` package to mimic the layout you shown in the figure. You could change the font size according to your own preference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=1in,left=1.5in,right=1.5cm,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\huge}{\llap{\Huge\thesection\hspace{1.3em}}}{0pt}{}[\vspace{-10pt}\llap{\hbox{\color{gray!50}\rule{2.2em}{4pt}}}\vspace{-25pt}\hbox{\color{gray!50}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}}\addvspace{2cm}]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}{\llap{\thesubsection\hspace{2.5em}}}{0pt}{}[]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{\llap{\thesubsubsection\hspace{2.2em}}}{0pt}{}[]

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1][1-8]
\subsection{Function}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Next Section}
\lipsum[1][1-8]
\subsection{Function}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]